# Windows command for directory manipulation in PUTTY psftp

Tags: windows, putty

I am wondering what is the command in Windows to show the current local directory? I am now working in PUTTY psftp mode, so the current directory is not shown in prompt.

Also is there GUI for ssh and sftp under windows? I don't think PUTTY offer anything GUI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run a command against the local machine, use ! before the command. So to see the local current directory on a window machine use !cd (since CD by itself on windows reports the current directory). To see the directory listing of the current directory use !dir instead (which would also show what the current directory path is along with the directory contents).

For graphical SFTP programs, there is WinSCP as mentioned by Slobo, as well as Filezilla. There may be others since most FTP programs probably have started including SFTP support along with normal FTP support (and SCP as well quite possibly).

Comment: Thanks! Why local directory does not change with "! cd .."? My current directory is always "C:\Windows\system32".

Comment: To change the local directory you use the lcd command (without the ! character). So if you type in at the ftp prompt 'lcd C:\windows' you'd change the local directory to C:\Windows.

Answer (score 2):

For GUI SFTP client see WinSCP http://winscp.net/eng/index.php